# Second level menu in Bootstrap navigation bar showing hidden links

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap in an ASP.NET application with C#. I have two level menu, with some option available to user and others to admin. The page load in the master page determines the options to show or hide the links in the menu. it works fine in the desktop mode, but in the mobile its showing the hidden links also which should only be shown to the admin.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item active">
        <asp:LinkButton class="nav-link" ID="LinkButton5" runat="server" Visible="false" PostBackUrl="#">Link 01</asp:LinkButton>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item active">
        <asp:LinkButton class="nav-link" ID="LinkButton6" runat="server" Visible="false" PostBackUrl="#">Link 02</asp:LinkButton>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item active">
        <asp:LinkButton class="nav-link" ID="LinkButton4" runat="server" Visible="false" PostBackUrl="#">Link 03</asp:LinkButton>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item active">
        <asp:LinkButton class="nav-link" ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" Visible="false" PostBackUrl="#">Link 04</asp:LinkButton>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item active">
        <asp:LinkButton class="nav-link" ID="LinkButton7" runat="server" Visible="false" PostBackUrl="#">Link 05</asp:LinkButton>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a runat="server" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown04" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" Visible="false">Link With Sub Menu</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown04">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sublink 01</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sublink 02</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SubLink 03</a>        
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item active">
        <asp:LinkButton class="nav-link" ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Visible="true" PostBackUrl="#">Link 06</asp:LinkButton>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item active">
        <asp:LinkButton class="nav-link" ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" Visible="False" OnClick="LinkButton3_Click">Link 07</asp:LinkButton>
    </li>                           
</ul>
```

The code behind is

```
if (Session["PersonType"] != null && Session["PersonType"].Equals("Admin"))
{
    LinkButton1.Visible = false;
    LinkButton2.Visible = false;
    dropdown04.Visible = true;
    LinkButton3.Visible = true;
    LinkButton4.Visible = false;
    LinkButton5.Visible = true;
    LinkButton6.Visible = true;
    LinkButton7.Visible = true;
}
else
{
    LinkButton1.Visible = true;
    LinkButton2.Visible = true;
    LinkButton3.Visible = false;
    LinkButton4.Visible = true;
    LinkButton5.Visible = false;
    LinkButton6.Visible = false;
    LinkButton7.Visible = false;
    dropdown04.Visible = false;
}
```

The dropdown04 menu items are shown even when the admin is not logged in. But it is only shown in the mobile mode and not in the desktop mode. Desktop mode is working fine. Issue is only in the mobile mode.

Some have suggested to add data-toggle to data-bs-toggle and data-target to data-bs-target, but it did not solve the issue for me rather it stops expanding the menu in the mobile view.

Comment: Do you have a mobile site admin page? (but are not using it)??? The just delete it. If your posted code behind runs in the page load event, then this should work. What page event are you running your above posted code? (and we assume that the code is NOT in the !isPostBack code stub in the page load event, but runs each time, correct?

Comment: Yes, this code runs in page load every time.
There is no condition in page load. 
This code is basically in master page.

Answer (score 0):

The original code had the a element with visible property.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item active">
        <asp:LinkButton class="nav-link" ID="LinkButton5" runat="server" Visible="false" PostBackUrl="#">Link 01</asp:LinkButton>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item active">
        <asp:LinkButton class="nav-link" ID="LinkButton6" runat="server" Visible="false" PostBackUrl="#">Link 02</asp:LinkButton>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item active">
        <asp:LinkButton class="nav-link" ID="LinkButton4" runat="server" Visible="false" PostBackUrl="#">Link 03</asp:LinkButton>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item active">
        <asp:LinkButton class="nav-link" ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" Visible="false" PostBackUrl="#">Link 04</asp:LinkButton>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item active">
        <asp:LinkButton class="nav-link" ID="LinkButton7" runat="server" Visible="false" PostBackUrl="#">Link 05</asp:LinkButton>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a runat="server" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown04" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" Visible="false">Link With Sub Menu</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown04">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sublink 01</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sublink 02</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SubLink 03</a>        
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item active">
        <asp:LinkButton class="nav-link" ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Visible="true" PostBackUrl="#">Link 06</asp:LinkButton>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item active">
        <asp:LinkButton class="nav-link" ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" Visible="False" OnClick="LinkButton3_Click">Link 07</asp:LinkButton>
    </li>                           
</ul>
```

After some trial and error I put the visible property in the li element. and made it runat server. and it is working so far.

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown" id="ddropDown04" runat="server" Visible="true">
        <a runat="server" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown04" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true">Link With Sub Menu</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown04">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sublink 01</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sublink 02</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SubLink 03</a>        
          </div>
        </li>
```

and my code behind now changes the visibility of ddropDown04. and I removed the visibility element from a element.